# Preferred mail format select does not set current value

Tags: ui

When editing preferred email format in 4.7.10, the select is not prefilled with it's current db value. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this on multilingual environment ? As I think somewhat related got fixed in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17778

Comment: Nope. Full german environement.

Comment: And in our envirgonment format "both" is preselected when creating contacts. 
But existing contacts holding "Both" in the db do not have "Both" preselected when editing – neither in edit form nor in contacts summary's in-place-editing.

Comment: This has been fixed in version 4.7.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been fixed in the updated version https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19135.

So it's recommended if you could upgrade CiviCRM to 4.7.11 or apply this patch to your site and check if it works for you https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8777